# How to fake InitialContext with default constructor

Tags: java, unit-testing, initial-context

All,

I'm trying to do some unit testing in some archaic java code (no interfaces, no abstraction, etc.)

This is a servlet that uses a ServletContext (which I'm assuming is set up by Tomcat) and it has database information is set up in the web.xml/context.xml file. Now, I've figured out how to make a Fake ServletContext, but the code has

```
 InitialContext _ic = new InitialContext();
```

all over the place (so it isn't feasible to replace it). I need to find a way to make a default InitialContext() able to do the `_ic.lookup(val)` without throwing an exception.

I'm assuming there is some way that the context.xml is getting loaded, but how that magic works, I'm drawing a blank. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Just because it occurs a lot doesn't mean it's definitely infeasible to replace it. Heck, even just changing to use a static factory method would allow *more* testability (although it's clearly not as nice as some alternatives).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/) to mock construction of the InitialContext and control its behavior. Constructor Mocking is documented [here](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor).

PowerMock tests can be quite messy and complicated, refactoring is normally a better option.

Comment: +1. PowerMock is powerful but it's definitely caused enough headaches that refactoring is much preferred.

Comment: I think this is the best solution for what i'm trying to do. thanks!

Comment: Avoid PowerMock unless you have no other option left open to you... Plenty of articles explaining why.

Answer (score 37):

Take advantage of the fact that `InitialContext` uses an SPI to handle its creation. You can hook into its lifecycle by creating an implementation of `javax.naming.spi.InitialContextFactory` and passing that to your tests via the system property `javax.naming.factory.initial` (`Context.INTITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY`).  It's simpler than it sounds.

Given this class:

```
public class UseInitialContext {

    public UseInitialContext() {
        try {
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            Object myObject = ic.lookup("myObject");
            System.out.println(myObject);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

And this impl of `InitialContextFactory`:

```
public class MyInitialContextFactory implements InitialContextFactory {

    public Context getInitialContext(Hashtable<?, ?> arg0)
            throws NamingException {

        Context context = Mockito.mock(Context.class);
        Mockito.when(context.lookup("myObject")).thenReturn("This is my object!!");
        return context;
    }
}
```

Creating an instance of `UseInitialContext` in a junit test with

```
-Djava.naming.initial.factory=initial.context.test.MyInitialContext
```

on the command line outputs `This is my object!!` (easy to set up in eclipse).  I like [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) for mocking and stubbing.  I'd also recommend Micheal Feather's [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052) if you deal with lots of legacy code. It's all about how to find seams in programs in order to isolate specific pieces for testing.

Comment: Instead of 'java.naming.initial.factory', I think the correct system property is 'java.naming.factory.initial'. At least in java 6. Thanks for the post!

Comment: 'java.naming.factory.initial' is also for java 7.

Comment: FWIW, i wrote a very similar answer to a very similar question some time after this, and i did this [using a JUnit `TestTule` to handle the setup and teardown](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17083737/116639).

Comment: Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY so you don't want to remember the actual string value for the initial context factory environment variable name.

Answer (score 6):

Here's my solution to setting up the Inintial Context for my unit tests. First I added the following test dependency to my project:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
  <artifactId>catalina</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.33</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then I created a static method with the following code:

```
public static void setupInitialContext() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
    System.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.apache.naming");
    InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
    ic.createSubcontext("jdbc");
    PGSimpleDataSource ds = new PGSimpleDataSource();
    ds.setDatabaseName("postgres");
    ds.setUser("postgres");
    ds.setPassword("admin");
    ic.bind("jdbc/something", ds);
}
```

Finally in each of my test class I add an @BeforeClass method which calls setupInitialContext.

Comment: in relation to this https://blogs.oracle.com/randystuph/entry/injecting_jndi_datasources_for_junit
was very good

Answer (score 4):

Try setting up the system variables before:

```
System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
        "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
System.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,
        "org.apache.naming");
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
```

If you are using JUnit, follow this doc: https://blogs.oracle.com/randystuph/entry/injecting_jndi_datasources_for_junit

Comment: This gives `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory`

Comment: you are supposed to have the tomcat environment in your project. You have to add the tomcat jars

Comment: So if I am using JBoss I guess I have to use JBoss environment. Thank you!

Comment: The link to oracle blog is broken

Answer (score 1):

Today I've faced the same problem (we can't user PowerMock) and solved it this way:

1. Don't lookup in the constructor so when you invoke @InitMock on the object, the constructor doesn't require the context yet.
2. Create a method for retrieving the service bean when needed like "getService().serviceMethod(param, param ...)":

> ```
>     /* Class ApplicationResourceProvider */
>
>     /* We can mock this and set it up with InjectMocks */
>     InitialContext ic;
>
>     /* method hiding the lookup */
>     protected ApplicationService getService() throws NamingException {
>         if(ic == null)
>             ic = new InitialContext();
>         return (ApplicationService)ic.lookup("java:global/defaultApplicationLocal");
>     }
> ```

3. On the test, set it up:

> ```
> @Mock
> ApplicationService applicationServiceBean;
>
> @Mock
> InitialContext ic;
>
> @InjectMocks
> ApplicationResourceProvider arp;
>
> @Before
> public void setUp() throws Exception {
>     MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
>     when(ic.lookup(anyString())).thenReturn(applicationServiceBean);
>     ...
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/)?

It's as easy as:

> InitialContext ctx = mock(InitialContext.class);

By the way, should you choose to use mocks i would recommend reading this article as well: http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html

Answer (score 0):

A poor man's standalone implementation using no external libraries:

```
public class myTestClass {
    public static class TestContext extends InitialContext {
        public TestContext() throws NamingException {
            super(true /*prevents initialization*/);
        }

        static Object someExpectedValue = "the expected string or object instance";

        /*override the method(s) called by the legacy program on _ic, check the parameter and return the wanted value */
        public Object lookup(String name) throws NamingException {
            return name != null && name.equals("theValueOfVal") ? someExpectedValue : null;
        }
    }

    public static class TestInitialContextFactory implements InitialContextFactory {
        public Context getInitialContext(Hashtable<?, ?> arg0) throws NamingException {
            return new TestContext();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "the.package.myTestClass$TestInitialContextFactory");
        /*now call the legacy logic to be tested*/
        ...
```

You could use a `switch` in the override of the `lookup` method to return the expected value for each different `val` value passed to `_ic.lookup(val)` throughout the legacy program.